# RoR select_tag default value & options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I set a default value using `select_tag`, and how can I keep the options open on page load?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

If you are using `select_tag` without any other helper, then you can do it in html:

```
select_tag "whatever", "<option>VISA</option><option selected=\"selected\">MasterCard</option>"
```

Or with `options_for_select`:

```
select_tag "whatever", options_for_select([ "VISA", "MasterCard" ], "MasterCard")
```

Or with `options_from_collection_for_select`:

```
select_tag [SELECT_FIELD_NAME], options_from_collection_for_select([YOUR_COLLECTION], [NAME_OF_ATTRIBUTE_TO_SEND], [NAME_OF_ATTRIBUTE_SEEN_BY_USER], [DEFAULT_VALUE])
```

Example:

```
select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, 'id', 'name', '1')
```

Examples are from [`select_tag` doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002249), [`options_for_select` doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M002306) and from [`options_from_collection_for_select` doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M002307).

Comment: Right and its confusing because the form builder select accepts different parameters

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<%= select_tag(:option, options_for_select([["Option 1",1],["Option 2",2],["Option 3",3]], params[:option] ), class:"select") %>
```

works great in rails 5.

Comment: Simple and easy to understand. How to pass this value [["Option 1",1],["Option 2",2],["Option 3",3]] from a model for a cleaner code?

Answer (score 3):

For options_for_select

```
<%= select_tag("products_per_page", options_for_select([["20",20],["50",50],["100",100]],params[:per_page].to_i),{:name => "products_per_page"} ) %>
```

For options from collection for select

```
<%= select_tag "category","<option value=''>Category</option>" +  options_from_collection_for_select(@store_categories, "id", "name",params[:category].to_i)%>
```

Note that the selected value which you are specifying must be of type value.
  i.e. if value is in integer format then selected value parameter should also be integer.

Comment: `"<option value=''>Category</option>".html_safe`

Answer (score 0):

Its already explained, Will try to give an example for achieving the same without options_for_select

let the select list be

```
select_list = { eligible: 1, ineligible: 0 }
```

So the following code results in

```
<%= f.select :to_vote, select_list %>

<select name="to_vote" id="to_vote">
  <option value="1">eligible</option>
  <option value="0">ineligible</option>
</select>
```

So to make a option selected by default we have to use **selected: value**.

```
<%= f.select :to_vote, select_list, selected: select_list.can_vote? ? 1 : 0 %>
```

if **can_vote?** returns true it sets **selected: 1** then the first value will be selected else second.

```
select name="driver[bca_aw_eligible]" id="driver_bca_aw_eligible">
  <option value="1">eligible</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="0">ineligible</option>
</select>
```

if the select options are just a array list instead of hast then the selected will be just the value to be selected for example if

```
select_list = [ 'eligible', 'ineligible' ]
```

now the selected will just take

```
<%= f.select :to_vote, select_list, selected: 'ineligible' %>
```

Answer (score -3):

another option (in case you need to add data attributes or other)

```
= content_tag(:select) do
  - for a in array
    option data-url=a.url selected=(a.value == true) a.name
```