# Rails options_for_select with selected model value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
f.select     :engine_value, options_for_select(engine_values_select_items)
```

As you can see, it's just simply a select list with options. The problem is that even if my form object has got Float value in engine_value this value is not selected in select tag. How can I fix this?

Code for engine_values_select_items:

```
def engine_values_select_items
    (1..6).step(0.1).to_a.map{|s| [s.round(2), s.round(2)]}
end
```

I thought Rails did this by default, but perhaps I am wrong?

Comment: Just add the selected value as second argument for `options_for_select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can remember myself dealing with those issues. IMHO in those cases the approach I followed was to meet my expectations with similar "generators" and combinations of them.

There is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396025/ror-select-tag-default-value-options) that might help you.

Also do not forget to check out the [proper syntax](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) (I am talking about order).

Then, try using "selected: " to see how you go.

Hope it helps,