# Make the default option of select tag to be of current value of name in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This piece of code is in my edit user attributes page. I have a subscription_type:string attribute for my model User in my rails app. The default value of the attribute is "". I want the select tag to show the option to be of the current value of subscription_type ("", Silver, Gold or Platinum) for the particular user. How can I achieve this?

```
<select class="form-group" name = "user[subscription_type]">
   <option value="">Select your subscription type</option>
   <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
   <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
   <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
</select>
```

Comment: see this [post](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/183829) if helps and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396025/ror-select-tag-default-value-options)

Comment: if you're not opposed to bringing in a gem, [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) has a number of valuable methods and helper flags for situations like this.

Comment: @ABMagil just looked into it! great and simple to use! will include it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want to use the [select_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) and the [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) methods and pass it an array of arrays- something like

`options_for_select([['Gold', 'Gold'], ['Silver', 'Silver'],['Platinum', 'Platinum']], @user.subscription_type)`