# Selected value in select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to select default option using select_tag. Here is my collection

```
@model_names = {
  'Fixed' => 'fixed',
  'Variable' => 'variable',
  'LIBOR' => 'libor'
}
```

And here is the select_tag

```
select_tag "second_model", options_for_select(@model_names, 'LIBOR')
```

I tried both 'LIBOR' and 'libor'. And even {'LIBOR' => 'libor'} as second parameter for `options_for_select`. But it doesn't work. How can I set default option when the collection is a hash?

//edit

oh, it works with 'libor' and... disabled JavaScript. I use selectBoxIt plugin and it doesn't work with it. Anyone knows how to select default value using Rails + selectBoxIt jQuery plugin?

Comment: It looks like you may be able to use `data-selectedtext` in the select tag's html attributes. See: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/#HTML5DataAttributeOptions

Answer (score 0):

If you try setting your variable as an array instead of an hash it might work better to set a default option. Then you can do something like options_for_select([['Default', 'default'][@model_names]]). In your drop it will default to default and have your collection in the drop down. You can mess around with it here are a couple of links to help.

[RoR select_tag default value & options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396025/ror-select-tag-default-value-options)

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select