# How to pass selected value in select tag through form_tag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to pass selected option values in rails form tag.Below code I am using.When I click Add to User group button,it will call addToUserGroups action.I need to get selected dropdown value when I click this button.

```
               <%= form_tag(contoller: "custom_group", action: "addToUserGroups") do%>
                <%=submit_tag "Add to User Group", class: "btn mx-auto btn-primary",  style:   "width: 200px"%> 
              <% end %>
```

I need to send this selected dropdown value to addToUserGroups controller.How to achieve this?

```
<select id="select-update" class="form-control">
            
           
               <% @all_execgroup_list.each do |parameter| %>
               <option value="<%= parameter['groupname'] %>"><%= parameter['groupname']%></option>
             <% end %>
           </select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RoR select\_tag default value & options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396025/ror-select-tag-default-value-options)

Comment: no.My question is here different.Pass this param "<%= parameter['groupname'] %> to form tag

Comment: Using the select tag you can set default selection. https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "select" option which is the second argument in the `options_for_select' helper.

```
<%= f.select :color, options_for_select(@color_options, selected: @color_value) %>
```

The important part here is `selected: @color_value`

Verbose version:

```
<%= f.select :color, options_for_select([["Blue", "blue"],["Green","Green"],["Yellow","yellow"]], selected: "yellow") %>
```

Yellow will be the default selected value in the dropdown.

`options_for_select` first argument takes a 2d array. What gets displayed in the dropdown is in first element in the array and the value is the second element in the array.

`[["Display Name", "value"],["Display Name 2", "value 2"]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use select_tag for that, like below

`<%= select_tag :field_name_here, options_for_select(all_execgroup_list.all) %>`